# Level sets of sum of heights of product of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I'm trying to calculate the level sets of the function $f:S^2 \times S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, that evaluates the sum of the heights on the spheres, i.e.:

$f(x,y) = h(x) + h(y)$

Where $h$ is the height function on the sphere.

The critical points of this function are $(s,s), (s,n), (n,s), (n,n)$, where $n,s$ are the north and south pole respectfully. That gives the critical values $-2, 0, 2$.

The level sets of the values $-2, 2\ $ are the single points $(s,s), (n,n)$, and the level set of $0$ is homeomorphic to the suspension of a torus.

For the level set of all other values, take for example $1$, I got a something that resembles a suspension of a torus, but in the "corners" of the suspension I have a copy of $S^1$, instead of a point. At first, I was tempted to say it is probably homeomorphic to $S^2 \times S^1$, but using Van Kampen we can see that the level set is simply connected (if I'm not mistaken).

My question is: Are this function's level sets of regular points homeomorphic to some nice known space? maybe $S^3$?

Comment: Now I'm wondering - Does Poincare conjecture shows that it's in fact a 3-sphere? Even if it does, I am still interested in an elementary solution. In particular, I want to see if it can be generalized to height functions on products of two n-spheres.

Comment: Are you familiar with Morse theory? I believe $f$ is a Morse function, in which case the level sets you're interested in can be identified with the boundary of four-dimensional discs, i.e. $S^3$.

Comment: I am studying Morse theory at the moment, that's how I got to this question actually. But I'm not familiar with the results yet. Why can it be identified with the boundary of four-dimensional discs? can you maybe send me to a reference or give me some keywords to find where it comes from?

Comment: Is that related to stable/unstable manifolds? Or am I way off?

Comment: Milnor's book on Morse theory is my go to. Also, I may be missing something, so it may not be as simple as what I state.

Comment: Is the general (non-formal) idea something like - Take the flow from $(n,n$) downwards, up to the time where the "boundary" of the submanifold covered by the flow is the level set of energy=1, and since we didn't go through any critical values, it's diffeomorphic to a 4-cell (where 4 is the index of the maximum point), and so the level set is the 3-sphere?

Comment: That's the idea, yes.

Comment: If you're interested, feel free to add these comments as an answer, and I'll accept it.